# Multi Tenancy approach - UserId to N Tenants

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Can I register same user (login/e-mail) in more than on tenant, so an UserId can belong to multiple Tenants?

I ask that because instead of input Tenant on login, How hard is to achieve this approach below?

When user logs in, if they belong to multiple tenants, boilerplate will identify this and show the user a select dropdown to choose which tenant they want to manage.
I feel this approach is more professional than input a tenant string value on login page.

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible in aspnetboilerplate structure. a user must belong to only a single tenant.

Comment: Is it still not possible now in 2023? What are your thoughts on this now?